# IP address accessable on local machine but not over the internet

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, ip

I have a windows server 2008 machine that I use for IIS.
I usually host all my sites on one IP address, my main IP. However, I needed to host a site with SSL, so I created a new site in IIS manager binded to a previously unused IP address.

However, I just cannot manage to access the site from any other computer. The site works fine if I access it from the browser on the server, but it just won't work if I try to access it from any other computer. I tried pinging the IP address, but it does not respond.

any ideas?
thanks

edit:
the ipconfig:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8139C+ Fast Ethernet NIC
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-16-3E-C9-D0-64
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4d23:966c:6c45:ad74%11(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 176.61.136.93(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 176.61.136.94(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 176.61.136.104(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 176.61.136.105(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 176.61.136.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 234886718
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-14-48-AD-77-00-16-3E-09-7C-CE

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

I used to host the sites on 176.61.136.104, and now I want to host one on 176.61.136.105, but it seems like I cannot ping 176.61.136.105 (but pinging 176.61.136.104 does work). However, I can ping both on the server.

Comment: Did you just randomly pick some IP address, or was this IP address assigned to your computer but not used?

Comment: it is assigned to the computer, and I can successfully see it in ipconfig. I can also access the site if I visit the ip address on the server's browser

Comment: Please tell us more about your environment. Also post an `ipconfig /all` of that server

Comment: I added it, plus some more description regarding the error. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ping and access the site locally on the server but not from another machine and this is a web server which means it is likely sitting behind a firewall. 
1) Have you confirmed the firewall rules allow the connection? 
2) Have you tried ping/http from another machine on the same subnet? 
3) Is there a host-based firewall on the server that needs to be configured to allow access to the new IP?